# Saving objects of any type to IPad/IPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, serialization, odata

This somewhat follows on from the question [Saving application data to the ipad/iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174628/saving-application-data-to-ipad-iphone)

Really I want to know if there is a way to store objects to the actual device not using Core Data. Im using the Odata Objective c SDK and I want to be able to save an entity to the disk of the device. The entity does not support the NSCoding protocol so I cant convert it to NSData and save it into NSData.

I just want some mechanism that allows me to download a list of objects from my odata service using the OData Objective C sdk, than save these objects to disk. So if the users kills the app/restarts the device, than I can just retrieve these objects from the iphone/ipad disk and use it in the app.

I dont think I am recreating the wheel here (I do this quite easily in .net by serializing the ojects to xml and saving it as an xml file on disk), im sure someone has stored objects to the device outside of core data. Or if there is a way to do this using core data than I am all ears?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To understand your needs, you really need to explain why you don't want to use Core Data, since your question is largely the same as your previous one, and the answers there were "definitely use Core Data". And ignore the person there who said Core Data was complex; it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you subclass the entities that you want to persist and implement the NSCoder protocol in the subclass? You can handle serialisation of the properties in the subclass and just pass those subclasses in to your Odata library.